# how to make my character move in the direction of my camera in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make it so that when I hold w, instead of going in a single direction, it goes forward in the direction my camera is facing.

My code is below.

```
{
   public CharacterController controller;
   public float speed = 12f;

   void Update()
   {
       float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
       float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

       Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

       controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the camera's transform, and use the `right` and `forward` field of the camera's transform instead of that of the player:

```
Camera mainCam;
public CharacterController controller;
public float speed = 12f;

void Awake()
{
    mainCam = Camera.main; // expensive operation, so cache the results
}


void Update()
{
    float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 move = mainCam.transform.right * x + mainCam.transform.forward * z;

    // normalize move if has a magnitude > 1 to prevent faster diagonal movement
    if (move.sqrMagnitude > 1)
    {
        move.Normalize();
    }

    controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If it's 2D game you can just make that camera is child of player but it can make problems in 3D games when character is rotating.

Comment: its a 3d game sorry probably should have specified